# Why is my c != 'o' || c != 'x' condition always true?

Tags: conditional-statements, logical-operators, logical-or

I have this loop statement, which I'll express using C-like syntax (C, C++, Java, JavaScript, PHP, etc. all use similar syntax):

```
while (c != 'o' || c != 'x') {
    c = getANewValue();
}
```

I want it to run until I get a `'o'` or `'x'`, but it never exits, even when `c` is `'o'` or `'x'`. Why not?

I've also tried using `if`:

```
if (c != 'o' || c != 'x') {
    // Show an error saying it must be either 'o' or 'x'
}
```

but that also always shows the error message, even when `c` is `'o'` or `'x'`. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It must be `if(c!='o' && c!='x')` instead of `if(c!='o' || c!='x')`. If you use the `or` operator the boolean expression will be always true.

Answer (score 11):

The condition `(c != 'o' || c != 'x')` can never be false. If `c` is `'o'`, then `c != 'x'` will be true and the OR condition is satisfied. If `c` is `'x'`, then `c != 'o'` will be true and the OR condition is satisfied.

You want `&&` (AND), not `||` (OR):

```
while (c != 'o' && c != 'x') {
    // ...
}
```

"While `c` is NOT `'o'` AND `c` is NOT `'x'..." (e.g., it's neither of them).

Or use De Morgan's law, [covered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127694/how-to-understand-de-morgan-laws-boolean-expression):

```
while (!(c == 'o' || c == 'x')) {
    // ...
}
```

"While it's NOT true that (`c` is `'o'` or `c` is `'x'`)..."

Answer (score 2):

> Why is my `c != 'o' || c != 'x'` condition always true?

The expression combines two sub-expressions using the logical `OR` operator (`||`). The expression is `true` if at least one of the sub-expressions is `true`. In order to be `false`, both sub-expressions it connects must be `false`.

The sub-expressions are `c != 'o'` and `c != 'x'`.

The first sub-expression `c != 'o'` is `false` when `c == 'o'`. The same for the second one; it is `false` when `c == 'x'`.

Please note that they cannot be `false` on the same time because `c` cannot be `'o'` and `'x'` on the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The condition should be `if(!(c=='o' || c=='x'))` or `if(c!='o' && c!='x')`

Answer (score 0):

even when you enter x or you enter o in that case if condition evaluates to true and hence game_start remains false.

it should be `if(c!='o' && c!='x')`
 or use a more straight forward way

```
if(c == 'o' || c == 'x')
   game_start=true;
else
    System.out.println("you can only enter o or x!");
```