# Not sure why != doesn't work when == does

Tags: python-3.x

Working through EDX python course. Not sure why when I use '!=' with 'or' statement code doesn't work as expected.

But I use '==' it does work.

```
x = input("Enter a letter: ")
if x == 'h' or x =='l' or x =='c':
    print('Correct letter')
else:
    print('Wrong letter')

x = input("Enter a letter: ")
if x != 'h' or x !='l' or x !='c':
    print('Wrong letter')    
else:
    print('Correct letter')
```

in the x variable example: entering 'h','l','c' prints 'correct letter' anything else prints 'wrong letter'

in the y variable example: entering 'h','l','c' prints 'wrong letter' all the time

Comment: Where's the y variable?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why non-equality check of one variable against many values always returns true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26337003/why-non-equality-check-of-one-variable-against-many-values-always-returns-true)

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36605454/why-is-my-c-o-c-x-condition-always-true.

Comment: That's the correct logic.  Entering 'h' will fail the first criteria, but will satisfy the second criteria, so it will return 'Wrong letter'.

Comment: @bbhbottle If for an `if` condition, even if one of the `or` clause is evaluated as `True` which is equal to `1`, the whole `if` clause has a cumulative result as `True` even though others may fail. When you have a possible set of values, better use `in`, and all the possible values in form of a list. And I think your second variable should be `y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of basic logic. If `x == 'h'` then it will automatically be `x != 'l'` and will be `x != 'c'`, which mean that when you substitute it with logical values it ends as `false or true or true` which is naturally `true`. Negation of alternative is conjunction of negations by [de Morgan's Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `OR` with `AND` should solve your problem.  You need all condition to be satisfied

```
x = input("Enter a letter: ")
if x != 'h' and x !='l' and x !='c':
    print('Wrong letter')    
else:
    print('Correct letter')
```